# Wrap First Character after </h3><p> in a <span> tag

Tags: php, filters, the-content, regex, customization

This is a continuation from a question I asked earlier about doing this with output from `the_excerpt()`.

What I am trying to do is take the following output from `the_content()` to take the following output as it currently is:

```
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

And have it do the following:

```
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p><span class="dropcap">P</span>aragraph</p>
```

I successfully did this with output from `the_excerpt()` using the following:

```
$the_excerpt = preg_replace('/^(.)/', '<span class="dropcap">\1</span>', $the_excerpt);
```

It works perfectly so I borrowed this line of code and modified it to:

```
$the_content = preg_replace( 
      '/(?<=\<\/h3\>\n<p>)./',
      '<span class="dropcap">\1</span>',
      $the_content
 );
```

When this filter runs it results in the following output:

```
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p><span class="dropcap"></span>aragraph</p>
```

But if I change the `'<span class="dropcap">\1</span>'` to a static character or string like '@', then it works.

What do I need to change the replacement string to? Seems weird to me that it works in the case of `the_excerpt()` but not for `the_content()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major issue is just that you have a [`positive lookbehind`](https://regex101.com/library/sB3yN5) but no `capture group` so `\1` or `$1` isn't a usable variable.

Fix your [regex](https://regex101.com/) to provide the capture group: `'/(?<=\<\/h3\>\n<p>)(.)/'` then reference as `$1`.

```
ob_start();?>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
<?php

$search = ob_get_clean();    

$result = preg_replace( 
        '/(?<=\<\/h3\>\n<p>)(.)/', 
        '<span class="dropcap">$1</span>', $search );
```

Answer (score 1):

In case this is for styling with CSS you don't need to use a regular expression. 
With `h3 + p:first-letter` you should be able to style the first letter of a `<p>` after a `<h3>`.

Comment: I'm using Dropcap.js for more consistency across browsers to handle the styling. I just want PHP to generate the span tags rather than using JavaScript to insert them after the document loads.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=First-letter

Comment: And http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2 (adjacent sibling selector)